# New relic plugin on Eclipse Android

Tags: android, eclipse, newrelic

So I'm on a Mac with Eclipse and I'm trying to add the new relic plugin. I've already followed the instructions up to import.

`import com.newrelic.agent.android.NewRelic;`

But now when I try to add the code:
`NewRelic.withApplicationToken(mycode).start(this.getApplication());`

where mycode is just the id as String given to me by new relic. I get an error that says:

`Syntax error on token "withApplicationToken", = expected after this token`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be some error in where this line was added or how the token was formatted.
Here's the exact formatting for this code, in its context:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    NewRelic.withApplicationToken(
            "AA9b032a80e2658208a0180ec09ff1f059badb7756"
            ).start(this.getApplication());

    setContentView(R.layout.lookup);
```

That's just a demo token, I've altered some characters in my token so that you won't start sending to my dashboard :)

If that doesn't fix it, I would send a complete code snippet to New Relic in a support ticket, either under 'help' in your dashboard or at support@newrelic.com.

If you do open a ticket and there's a general solution, I'll come back here and post the right steps for other users.

Comment: i'm such a moron, i put this on the declaration part (facepalm) thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

This line looks fine. Is there a missing semicolon or something in the previous line? Can you verify that?